# Angular - router.navigate('/xxx') resolves with a 'false'

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular5

```
this.router.navigate(navtoURL).then((isNavigationSuccessfull: boolean) => {
// isNavigationSuccessfull...
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error
});
```

My 'router.navigate('/xxx')' call sometimes resolves with a 'false'. This happens randomly and does not seem to have a pattern. It does not go to the 'catch' method. If I retry the navigation, it seems to work. The failure happens randomly only on the first navigate.

On checking the navigation trace, I found the "NavigationCancel" event was being called with an empty('') "reason".

Can someone please tell me the scenarios when a 'navigate' could resolve with a 'false'?

Comment: Do you have any route guards?

Comment: Try enableTracing for RouterModule.

Comment: Is this angular2+ or AngularJS? Use tag `AngularJS` for angular <2

Comment: I have one Route Guard and it is returning 'true' even on navigation fail. So the Guard is not causing the issue

Comment: @sabithpocker: I added 'enableTracing' and the route fails with => NavigationCancel {id: 2, url: "/xxx/yyy/zzz", reason: ""}. No reason is being mentioned. Any suggestions?

Comment: Will be hard to debug with provided info.

Comment: @sabithpocker: please let me know if you need any more specific info. Thanks!

Comment: Your routing setup including both start and end routes would be a good start, including any redirects or guards you have in place. If you can copy it to a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) app to reproduce the issue it would be perfect. You may even stumble upon the actual issue if you try to isolate and reproduce the issue in stackblitz.